# Subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with connected boundary

Tags: general-topology

Let $ A \subset \mathbb R^2 $ (with Euclidean topology) be a **closed** set such that its boundary $\partial A$ is connected. How can you prove or disprove that $A$ is connected? What if $A$ is **compact**?

Comment: What did you try?